# winrun4j - Unable to create service

Tags: java, service, winrun4j

I have service created by using winrun4j with java application.
I am getting following error while installing service.

```
C:\LoginTester>service.exe --WinRun4J:RegisterService
[info] Module Name: C:\LoginTester\service.exe
[info] Module INI: C:\LoginTester\service.ini
[info] Module Dir: C:\LoginTester\
[info] INI Dir: C:\LoginTester\
[info] Registering Service...
[err] Could not create service: 1072
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(SC) DeleteService FAILED 1072](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305037/sc-deleteservice-failed-1072)

Comment: @Nameless One , your link question is completely related to WAS Services and profiles, not with Winrun4j and java..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it got resolved by **logging off all other users** on the server and closing of service manager, task manager applications.

Answer (score 0):

Service was unregistered and is marked for deletion. Reboot system.