# Uninstalling Windows Service

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-7, windows-services, uninstallation

I have uninstalled a `windows service` (In `Windows7`) using `installutil.exe` . This states that the uninstallation of the service is successful, then I restarted the server (
[How to force uninstallation of windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225275/how-to-force-uninstallation-of-windows-service)) but the service still runs properly without any problem.

When I try to delete the service using `sc delete`, it states that the service does not exist as an installed service.

I m using `.NET framework 3.5`.

Is there any way of uninstalling a successfully???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop the service, delete the files and remove the keys in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services

Edited to make HCLM be HKLM.  Phonics failed me last night.