# Why can't I install my windows service - Specified service already exists

Tags: c#, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I wish I could put a grenade to my computer at this point. I'm so frustrated because I don't understand why my application won't install using installUtil.

I've just looked through this link now:  [Windows Service Install Ends in Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499605/windows-service-install-ends-in-rollback) and unfortunately the kind suggestions on there don't help in my situation, the following error was generated after taking into consideration all of the answers posted by the good people of SO on that link and others.

I have looked for best practices on the web for task parallel processing patterns but there's nothing helpful so far. The latest error I get when attempting to install is as follows:

> .exe assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   E:\xxx\MyService\Service_V2.InstallLog. Installing assembly
>   'E:\xxx\MyService\Service_V2.exe'. Affected parameters are:
>   logtoconsole =    logfile = E:\xxx\MyService\Service_V2.InstallLog
>   assemblypath = E:\xxx\MyService\Service_V2.exe Installing service
>   Service V2... Service Service V2 has been successfully installed.
>   Creating EventLog source Service V2 in log Application... Installing
>   service Service V2... Creating EventLog source Service V2 in log
>   Application...
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service already
>   exists
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the E:\xxx\MyService\Service_V2 .exe assembly's
>   progress. The file is located at
>   E:\xxx\MyService\Service_V2.InstallLog. Rolling back assembly
>   'E:\xxx\MyService\Service_V2.exe'. Affected parameters are:
>   logtoconsole =    logfile = E:\xxx\MyService\Service_V2.InstallLog
>   assemblypath = E:\xxx\MyService\Service_V2.exe Restoring event log to
>   previous state for source Service V2. Restoring event log to previous
>   state for source Service V2. Service Service V2 is being removed from
>   the system... Service Service V2 was successfully removed from the
>   system.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed. The installation failed, and the
>   rollback has been performed.

There was nothing written to the event log either.

Here is my OnStart() method:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = tokenSource.Token;

            ErrorLogFileName = "Service_V2Errors" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt";
            Service_V2LogFile = "Service_V2Log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".log";

            ErrorLogPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Errorpath"].ToString();
            CheckBatchRecord = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CheckBatchTime"].ToString());

            if (!Directory.Exists(ErrorLogPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(ErrorLogPath);
            }

            LogMessage("Starting Service " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            _ErrorLog = new StreamWriter(ErrorLogPath + "//" + ErrorLogFileName, true);
            _ErrorLog.WriteLine("Error, Location, AdditionalInformation", true);
            _ErrorLog.Close();

            var t = Task.Run(() => Service_V2Start(), token);

            try
            {
                t.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                LogMessage("Exception messages:");
                foreach (var ie in e.InnerExceptions)
                    LogMessage(ie.GetType().Name + " : " + ie.Message);

                LogMessage("\nTask status: " + t.Status);       
            }
            finally
            {
                tokenSource.Dispose();
            }          
        }
```

I have also set the compile mode to release for the final install files compiled.

I have done an "sc delete Servie V2" and I also checked the services console and there is no such service listed there.

I have also tried the InstallUtil.exe -u command to uninstall, but I still get this nitwit error. What should I do now?

Comment: You did not post the correct code, this doesn't have anything to do with OnStart().  [Start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Did you run installutil  elevated? If not, please do. Do you call CreateEventSource in the constructor? If so, is it guarded against recreation?

Comment: I hope you started your command in "Run as administrator" mode...if not, this issue might be because of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Make sure your `Program.cs` file looks something like this:

   ```
   static class Program
   {
       static void Main()
       {
           var service = new YourServiceName();
           ServiceBase.Run(service);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Inside the `InitializeComponent()` method make sure that the `ServiceName` property value is the same as the `ServiceName` in the `ProjectInstaller.cs`

   ```
    this.ServiceName = "MyServiceName";//in the YourServiceName partial class

    this.myServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "MyServiceName";//in the installer
   ```
3. Make sure you have only one installer.
4. In the batch files that you created to install and uninstall your service make sure that you are pointing to the correct `InstallUtil.exe`.

   For **64** bit architectures you can use - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe

   For **32** bit architectures you can use - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
5. Sample InstallService.bat file:

   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe" "PathToTheExecutables\MyServiceName.exe"
   pause
6. Sample UninstallService.bat file:

   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe" /u "PathToTheExecutables\MyServiceName.exe"
   pause

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run cmd as Administrator :)